# How does Google classify which country a website belongs to?

Tags: google, traffic, search-engines, alexa, country-specific

How does Google determine which country a website belongs to?

Is this technique also used by Alexa.com?

I don't think that the website's location is determined by its host's IP address or by its WHOIS information.

I think the site's location is determined by by traffic statistics (the country with the most visitors to the site determines the site's location).

Answer (score 3):

From [Working with multi-regional websites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html)

> Google generally uses the following
>   elements to determine the geotargeting
>   of a website (or a part of a website):
>
> **Use of a ccTLD** is generally a strong signal for users since it
>   explicitly specifies a single country
>   in an unmistakable way.
>
> or
>
> **Webmaster Tools' manual geotargeting for gTLDs** (this can be on a domain,
>   subdomain or subdirectory level); more
>   information on this can be found in
>   our blog post and in the Help Center.
>   With region tags from geotargeting
>   being shown in search results, this
>   method is also very clear to users.
>   Please keep in mind that it generally
>   does not make sense to set a
>   geographic target if the same pages on
>   your site target more than a single
>   country (say, all German-speaking
>   countries) — just write in that
>   language and do not use the
>   geotargeting setting (more on writing
>   in other languages will follow soon!).
>   Server location (through the IP
>   address of the server) is frequently
>   near your users. However, some
>   websites use distributed content
>   delivery networks (CDNs) or are hosted
>   in a country with better webserver
>   infrastructure, so we try not to rely
>   on the server location alone.
>
> **Other signals** can give us hints. This could be from local addresses &
>   phone numbers on the pages, use of
>   local language and currency, links
>   from other local sites, and/or the use
>   of Google's Local Business Center
>   (where available).
>
> Note that we do not use locational
>   meta tags (like "geo.position" or
>   "distribution") or HTML attributes for
>   geotargeting. While these may be
>   useful in other regards, we've found
>   that they are generally not reliable
>   enough to use for geotargeting.

Answer (score 0):

little unsure as to the question, but if you are trying to determine how search engines define who your website is targeted at. I believe its based on a number of factors with URL / Server location / site language all being major indicators.

traffic patterns probably do impact listings as well although a lot of site feature across multiple listings 9i am thinking big brand .com here).